# facebook external login not redirect back

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC5 application with external login. When I use Facebook login, after I put in my login information into facebook login page, facebook fails to direct me back to my application.

I got a white page with the following URL in Chrome's URL bar:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=632877723495196&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMPOS%2Fsignin-facebook&scope=email&state=l2oJwWdkbRsgZHyr6-5lL9ZTZc-eMbRBkH73L-h1ZN_MWvWriNeEdCxuNspi4QptZAna60SQIJX4NB5AItzP6NxpDCz10m48JInWUfvQGWkgFgZhZNFIaTz6ju-kEQ-RyiObgiMOKvBougeeaSHD7CAzTrvc1Gj6XdGgGbUgyrM9d1KZUEGbqh_MdyBPg4wTFbQEiui-2GzvcIvhOVtTRC12NnhgnVyLCrrKEDFaWdU

If I use IE, I got "The website cannot display the page" error page with the following URL on the borwser's URL bar:

https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.1%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FMPOS%252Fsignin-facebook%26state%3DWbWcYquZJnjvo8Db42l6goqpMUrioHL6HBVIUMu74QvqMuAjNzWizophJhNpf3NHCbw1-Dw1tsdgmv2h1f0ct1zcLJ_jlSXQ3ImCHVN_PXRkRedVB3gjTQb59-tbxPKxJQTuNhPvOKLq6aBjakP_fJDw5zXKZ55LrRzHVzEQ39Qff7WXsNJpke2BTHILHLI0I5jcWiXEgE-HeH7La19ttaL9LhrcyXP4DBiWaXuUNZc%26scope%3Demail%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3D632877723495196%26ret%3Dlogin

Anyone has an answer to this problem? Thanks!

Thanks Nathan,  clear cache on browser didn't help. I tried to clear cache/cookies on both IE and Chrome several times before I post the question.

The weird thing is that if I create an app under my personal facebook account and use the FacebookAppID/FacebookAppSecret for my app, the external login works fine. That's how I did all my testing.

But when I try to deploy the website I want to create the app under company's facebook account. I set up the app under the company's facebook account exactly the same way as I did when using my personal facebook account, then I got this redirect problem.  If I switch back the FacebookAppID/FacebookAppSecret to the one I created under my personal account, everything works fine. That's even more puzzling.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache/cookies on IE?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the problem. I forgot to turn on "make this app and all its live features available to the general public" setting for the app I created in Facebook.  So the login was only available to the developer who created the app.  After I turn that setting on (it is under the Status and Review Tab), everything works fine.